# How to refer to a group having 3 men and 1 woman

Tags: characters, naming

I am rewriting a story that once had a group of 4 men. Throughout the story they were often referred to as the 4 men. Now the story is being updated to replace one of the male characters with a female. Now that the group is not all men, it does not seem proper to continue referring to them in various places as "the men". For example:

"The 4 men ran across the bridge."

While all characters are friends I don't think I want to refer to them as "the four friends." Using the above sample sentence as a guide you can see what I mean:

"The 4 friends ran across the bridge."

Since there is only one women in the group I'm not sure I like the following reference either:

"The 4 men and woman ran across the bridge."

I'm looking for some common solution to this reference problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect this should really be on [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com). At any rate, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with using "friends", so I don't quite see what the issue is. Some other suggestions for you: "The four of them  ran across the bridge.". Or, "The four companions  ran across the bridge." Or, just simply use "They ran across the bridge."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems a little odd to keep repeating the specific number of people in the group over and over. And there are a lot of synonyms for "group" (including the word "group" itself) that are not limited to a gender.

"The ___ ran over the bridge" could be filled with tons of words, such as:

group, party, characters, adventurers, explorers, warriors, people, etc.

Depending on your story, warriors might not be appropriate! but there are tons of variations of group names that would substitute for "The men ran over the bridge."

Comment: Agreed, what attributes does this group have in common other than gender? Are they rebels? Fighters? Conquistadors? And so on - you need to look at what the characters are and you will get the right word.

Comment: You could also say "the four", "the quartet" or "they".

Answer (score 1):

As Sarah Stark said, referring to a specific number of people over and over again is sloppy style as-is. It's the kind of thing Dan Brown does, and while his works are very marketable and page-turning, they're not known for their stylistic elegance.

Just say 'the group' ran over the bridge, 'the party', heck 'they' will work most of the time if the reader already knows 'they' refers to the group.

Don't be the guy to make every character into 'the 162cm man' or 'the white-haired woman', because it reads as amateurish.